# Error to connect with SQL Server

Tags: vb6

I have Runtime error that "Not associated with trusted SQL server connectiion" Please help me

Comment: Can you post your connectiong string?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you try to connect to a SQL Server db that has been set up with Windows Only Authentication (not Windows and SQL Server Authentication)...That can be changed if you have access to the DB.

See:  http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an authentication error with the SQL server.  Check your connection string and your SQL server's authentication settings.

More info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889615), and of course [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=Not+associated+with+trusted+SQL+server+connection).